# Facebook API - Not receiving real-time updates when post is edited from both user and page feed

Tags: facebook-graph-api

These are the scenarios that I'm receiving real-time updates from both user and page feed

1. Add a Post
2. Add a Comment
3. Edit a Comment
4. Like a Post
5. Unlike a Post

But I'm not receiving when the particular post is (edited)updated.

Comment: Could you post a piece of the code, in this case, where the updates are currently received? Also, why are you not able to?  It it an error message you received or something returning a null value?

Comment: I'm not receiving anything from facebook server in that case